# Problems with mounting an external harddrive on an Ubuntu server

Tags: 20.04, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, raid

I purchased myself a Banana Pi-M5 and a "Yottamaster 4-Bay Raidsystem". I Installed Ubuntu 20.04LTS on that Pi. My plan is to install Nextcloud using docker and store the data I saved at Nextcloud on that external raid system. After the installation I tried to mount my RAID system (ntfs) - it succeeded. I have started setting up Nextcloud and soon became a error, which was telling me to change the permissions to 0770. I tried but had no success... So I thought long and hard and came to the conclusion that ntfs is the wrong format (obviously) - after that I formatted the disk to ext4 but I still can't mount the disk anymore... even if when I use ntfs again.

I tried the following command to mount the disk:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/external
```

This command doesn't trow an error, but it also doesn't mount the disk.

`/dev/sda2` is my RAID System (I used `blkid` to find out) and `/mnt/external` is the path I want to get mounted.

I have a short summary for you what I did, may it help to understand my issue.

[image: I have a short summary for you what I did, may it help to understand my issue.]

I probably didn't give enough information, so please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: What are the permissions for the folder `/mnt/external ` before you try to mount the partition? What about after?

Comment: at first 777 later (0)770

I figured out what my problem was (at least I guess so) 
I removed the entire path and reinstalled nextcloud after that I was able to mount that path to the hard drive..